# Not getting all fields from class for insert into DB using SQLBulkTools

Tags: c#, sql, sqlbulkcopy

I am using the C# package https://github.com/tiagorosendo/SqlBulkTools.

I have a List of objects that contain the data that I want bulk inserted into my DB.

Here is my object:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace CFDE.Model
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OwnershipPeriod")]
    public class OwnershipPeriod : ChathamBase
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OwnershipPercentage")]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal")]
        public Nullable<decimal> OwnershipPercentage;


        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OwnershipPercentageEffectiveDate")]
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
        public Nullable<DateTime> OwnershipPercentageEffectiveDate;

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OwnershipStructure")]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
        public string OwnershipStructure;
    }
}
```

This is the Base Class (Nothing fancy).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CFDE.Model
{
    interface IChathamBase
    {
        int TransactionIdentifier { get; set; }
    }


    public class ChathamBase : IChathamBase
    {
        public int TransactionIdentifier { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is the code that I am using to upsert data into my DB.

```
internal static void BulkUpsert(string connectionName, List<OwnershipPeriod> op)
        {
           BulkOperations bulk = new BulkOperations();

            using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection(connectionName))
                {
                    bulk.Setup<OwnershipPeriod>()
                        .ForCollection(op)
                        .WithTable("OwnershipPeriod")
                        .AddAllColumns()
                        //.AddColumn(x => x.TransactionIdentifier)
                        //.AddColumn(x => x.OwnershipPercentage)
                        .BulkInsertOrUpdate()
                        //.SetIdentityColumn(x => x.TransactionIdentifier)
                        .MatchTargetOn(x => x.TransactionIdentifier)
                        .Commit(cn);
                }

                trans.Complete();
            }
        }
```

My issue is that my table in the DB has 4 columns.  The one from the base class and the 3 from the class. The only column that gets inserted/updated is the first column (from the base class).

I am using this same code for another class that also inherits from the same base class and it works fine.

The only thing I have identified is that the fields in this class all have Nullable datatypes, but I have no idea how to get around that. I need those marked as nullable as the XML that I am pulling in data from has those fields nullable.

Is there another way to pull them in from the XML during deserilization?

Is there another way to identify them to retrieve them for Insert into DB?

Looking for anything that can point me in the right direction....

Class that works

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    namespace CFDE.Model 
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "LoanIdentifiers")]
        public class LoanIdentifiers
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionIdentifier")]
            public int TransactionIdentifier { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionQuoteIdentifier")]
            public int TransactionQuoteIdentifier { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DebtIdentifier")]
            public string DebtIdentifier { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DebtDescription")]
            public string DebtDescription { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CorporateId")]
            public string CorporateId { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReferenceNumberInternal")]
            public string ReferenceNumberInternal { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReferenceNumberLender")]
            public string ReferenceNumberLender { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReferenceNumberLoan")]
            public string ReferenceNumberLoan { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReferenceNumberChatham")]
            public string ReferenceNumberChatham { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Hypo")]
            public string Hypo { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "TransactionCreateDate")]
            public DateTime TransactionCreateDate { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ScheduleLastModifiedDate")]
            public DateTime ScheduleLastModifiedDate { get; set; }
        }
    }




internal static void BulkUpsert(string connectionName, IEnumerable<LoanIdentifiers> li)
    {
        BulkOperations bulk = new BulkOperations();

        using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = GetConnection(connectionName))
            {
                bulk.Setup<LoanIdentifiers>()
                    .ForCollection(li)
                    .WithTable("LoanIdentifiers")
                    .AddAllColumns()
                    .BulkInsertOrUpdate()
                    //.SetIdentityColumn(x => x.TransactionIdentifier)
                    .MatchTargetOn(x => x.TransactionIdentifier)
                    .Commit(cn);
            }

            trans.Complete();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show us the other code sample that **is** working, so we can compare the two.

Comment: In c# putting a question mark after a number type makes it nullable like : decimal? myNumber = null;  Net library does not allow nulls for DateTime.  The best you can do is set it to the default value 1/1/01 using new DateTime().  So using a get/set property which reads/writes from xml as string you can parse the string to a DateTime if it is not null, or put into class new DateTime() if null.  A string you can set the default to string.Empty.

Comment: I believe I may have found my issue. I was missing the { get; set; } from the class that was not working therefore they were fields not properties which it looks like they need to be for the SQLBulkTools methods to work.

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out yourself, [SqlBulkTools only loops through the type's properties](https://github.com/olegil/SqlBulkTools/blob/d33329bd077e75c9f65aa3969318bd7b0821f1c0/SqlBulkTools/BulkOperationsHelpers.cs#L232), so all fields are ignored. The normal coding standard is to make all fields private, and use methods, properties, or indexers to expose private fields instead ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)), which is why they only check for properties.